# Apache FTPClient hangs during the retrieveFileStream

Tags: java, timeout, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

Dear all I have a problem with my code. My ftp client is sometimes hanging when it is retrieving a file with "ftpClient.retrieveFileStream()". Any idea what I can do? I am using apache commons FTP client v3.4.

- I tried also with "ftpClient.retrieveFile()" but it did not make any difference.
- setting the connection and scoket timeout did not help
- setting the passive mode did not help
- increasing the buffer did not help

  ```
          ftpClient = new FTPClient();
          ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
          ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);              
          ftpClient.connect(serverAddress);
          ftpClient.login(userName,password);
          ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
          ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
          ftpClient.setSoTimeout(10000);

          log("retriving file " + remoteFilePath + "...");
          OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath);
          InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFilePath); // here it is sometimes hanging.
          try {
              IOUtils.copy(inputStream, output);
              output.flush();
          } 
          finally {
              IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
              IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
              ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
          }
  ```

the last message I retrieve are looking usually like this:

```
19:58:21.145 [main] INFO  FTPDAO: retrieving file /Modell/5250/Artikel/25777/lg_keh68bgh_1.jpg...
19:58:21.145 [main] INFO  Log4JFTPCommandListener - >> PASV
19:58:21.462 [main] INFO  Log4JFTPCommandListener - << 227 Entering Passive Mode (195,216,65,165,168,240)
19:58:21.476 [main] INFO  Log4JFTPCommandListener - >> RETR /Modell/5250/Artikel /25777/lg_keh68bgh_1.jpg
19:58:21.490 [main] INFO  Log4JFTPCommandListener - << 150 Connection accepted
```

When I suspend the programm with the debugger, then it looks that is hanging at

```
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) 
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: 116 
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) line: 170   
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 141
```

regards
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I changed `retrieveFileStream` to `retrieveFile`. and it doesn't hang there anymore.

Comment: sadly in our usecase it hangs for both solutions :-/

Comment: @user2122552 Are you sure it is not a networking problem? Does an FTP client have the same problems?

Comment: I tried with retrieveFileStream and retrieveFile and both solutions didn't work out. I manually downloaded the directory with 'wget -r protocol:user:pw@IP' and that finished successful.
I cannot use a client with GUI because only the IP of the server is whitelisted